# Nautilus does not have permission to mount; webcam and scanner are only recognised if the program has superuser permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, fedora, sudo, systemd

I installed a minimal version of fedora 27 and have encountered several permission problems.

1. When I try to mount a USB Stick using Nautilus or PCManFM it displays «Not authorized to perform operation»
2. My Scanner and Webcam are not recognised by programs like Cheese or simple-scan. They are recognised and work if I start the programs with `sudo`.
3. `systemctl suspend` requires authentication or needs to be started using sudo.

For the third one I found some workaround by just defining in the sudoers file that my user does not need to enter the password for that command `systemctl suspend`. But it is still not perfect since I need to add sudo which was not required in the normal fedora gnome version.

I'm using fedora 27 with i3 and CDM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that CDM spawned the session on a different tty than the one I logged in on.

In `/etc/cdmrc` I set `xtty=1` and `locktty=yes` and after that I had an active session when I logged in with CDM.